# Localstorage is overriding the previous store data at index 0 instead of storing new data at index 1. Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I want to store mobile details entered by user in localstorage. This code is storing the first entered details of mobile but for the second input, details are overriding the previous information. The previous data is lost.

```
const MobileDetails = () => {
    //using hooks o store the data
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState({
        mobileName: '',
        brand: '',
        price: '',
        color: '',
        RAM: '',
        ROM:'',
    });

//save data in localstorage
const handleSubmit = () => {
        let mobileDetails = []
        mobileDetails.push(detail)
        localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(mobileDetails))
}

//updating detail 
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setDetail({
        ...detail,
        [name]: value
    })
}


return(
//input section
    <div>
        <h1>Enter Mobile Details</h1>
        <div className='inputContainer'>
            <TextField id="standard-search" name='mobileName' placeholder="Mobile Name" value= 
            {detail.mobileName} onChange={handleChange} type="search"/>
            <TextField id="standard-search" name='brand' placeholder="Brand" value={detail.brand} 
            onChange={handleChange} type="search"/>
            <button name='Submit' className='button' onClick={handleSubmit} >Submit </button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

`how to resolve this issue`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting `mobileDetails` to an empty array on each form submitting. To resolve this issue, You have 2 ways:

**First:** Saving mobile details in an array using `useState` hooks. Using this way on each page refresh you will lose your data again.

**Second:(Recommended if not losing data in refresh is important to you)**

Initialize your `mobileDetails` array using localStorage in your `handleSubmit`. Refactored code should be something like this:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    //Getting data from localStorage
    const savedMobileDetails = localStorage.getItem('data')

    //Check if data is available to parse or seeting empty array
    const mobileDetails = savedMobileDetails ? JSON.parse(savedMobileDetails) : []

    //Saving new data
    localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify([...mobileDetails,detail]))
}
```